# How to get the image of the image button?

Tags: android

I have 2 image button. imagebutton1 has a picture on it as a background and the imagebutton2 has a blank background. how can I make that if I click the imagebutton1, the imagebutton2 will get the background picture of the imagebutton1 and if I click again the imagebutton2, the background will be blank again. just like the concept of the game "4pic 1 word" if you guys are familiar with that. thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I'm still in the process of searching some tutorials

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromImageView(ImageView imageView){ 
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();       
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this..

```
int minute = 0;
final Drawable d = img2.getDrawable();
    img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (minute == 0) {
                img2.setImageDrawable(img1.getDrawable());
                minute = 1;
            } else {
                img2.setImageDrawable(d);
                minute = 0;
            }

        }
    });
    img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            img2.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
    });
```

Change the click event as your requirement.Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on click of button

```
                 public void firstbutton(){
                ImageView ImageButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
               ImageButton2 .setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                     }

             public void Secondbutton()
             ImageView ImageButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
             ImageButton2 .setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                         }


  call this method on button click where you want cheers........
```